# Unable to join HyperV VM to existing domain controller

Tags: networking, dns, active-directory, hyper-v

I just installed a new HyperV host in our network, and am configuring a few 2012R2 VMs off that host. The network already has an existing domain controller.

- DC.Domain.com - 192.168.1.3 (Server 2008)
- HyperV01 192.168.1.201 (Server 2012R2)

  - VM01 - 192.168.1.2 (Server 2012R2 - Primary DNS set to 192.168.1.3)
  - VM02 - 192.168.1.4 (Server 2012R2 - Primary DNS set to 192.168.1.3)
  - VM03 - 192.168.1.5 (Server 2012R2 - Primary DNS set to 192.168.1.3)

I can join HyperV01 to the domain just fine, so there shouldn't be a problem on the Domain Controller / DNS.

When I am trying to join any of the VMs to the domain, there is an error:

> DNS was successfully queried for the service location (SRV) resource record used to locate a domain controller for domain "domain.com":
>
> The query was for the SRV record for _ldap._tcp.dc._msdcs.domain.com
>
> The following domain controllers were identified by the query:
>   dc.domain.com
>
> However no domain controllers could be contacted.
>
> Common causes of this error include:
>
> - Host (A) or (AAAA) records that map the names of the domain controllers to their IP addresses are missing or contain incorrect addresses.
> - Domain controllers registered in DNS are not connected to the network or are not running.

I have tried to turn the firewall off on the HyperV host, but that did not help. 
These VM's are also unable to see the rest of the servers on the network, and they cannot see each other. Network Discovery is turned on...

I can ping the domain controller from the VM using both the hostname and FQDN...

I am at a loss....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Deleting and recreating the Virtual Switch on HyperV01 resolved this problem.